# Insert rows to table using hibernate if specific row does not contain database

Tags: hibernate

I have a table example customer. customer table contains column customerId. I am reading data from CSV file in which first column is  customer Id. I want to check this value exist in customer table and if there is no value, I want to insert that value in customer. and if exists, i have to update that record. This CSV file contains more than 1000 records. Would you please give me better way to impliment this using hibernate

Comment: I believe hibernate's Session.merge() will do just that. If the ID exists in the DB, the DB record is updated. If the ID does not exist, a new record is created.

Comment: Please, show the relevant Hibernate mappings.